# Fast iterating over 3D array with unsafe code?

Tags: c#, arrays, unmanaged, loops

I have a piece of code where I iterate through a huge 3D array with two for-loops. Now I have performance problems, it is just too slow. What can I do?

I read somewhere that unmanaged code could solve the problem. Did I understand right: Unmanaged Code runs outside the .net engine?

Well I put a unsafe-block arround my array iterations, but it didn't help. I think thats because I still use the managed array. How can I copy my array into a unsafe array or get an unsafe pointer to this array? I tried fixed (see code below) but I get compiler errors.

```
        byte[, ,] data = original.Data;
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte*** dataPtr = (byte***)data)  // data is of type byte[,,]
            {
                for (int i = original.Rows - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    for (int j = original.Cols - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                    {
                        if (dataPtr[i,j,0] < 100)
                        {
                           dataPtr[i, j, 0] += 100;
                           dataPtr[i, j, 1] += 40;
                           dataPtr[i, j, 2] += 243;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           dataPtr[i,j,0] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

How can I use this fixed keyword in an 3D array and would it help to make my code faster?

Comment: in the future, you can edit your tags or questions to provide more information by clicking the *edit* link just below the question body and tags.  The answers section is only for potential solutions to your problem.

Comment: Unsafe code is *not* unmanaged code. Unsafe just means that it cant be verified by the runtime and require higher privileges to execute. Unmanaged code is code outside of .NET Framework.

Comment: The compiler error is probably because `byte***` is the wrong type.  A multidimensional array is a single block of memory accessed through a `byte*` and some math to calculate the index (based on the individual indices and the array size).

Answer (score 2):

If you want speed, you don't use a multidimensional array. You need to use a `byte[][][]` jagged array, which is heavily optimized in the CLR. This single change will likely speed up your loops sufficiently that you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: No, you use a 1-D array with `rows*columns*planes` elements.  Much better data locality, fewer levels of indirection.